# Google Chart Tool - change language for xAxis

Tags: google-visualization

How to change (define) language (f.ex. france, polish, utf-8) to vAxis 
and YAxis titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your strings with with php's json_encode to use UTF-8 character encodings:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 400);
        data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
        data.setValue(1, 2, 460);
        data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 860);
        data.setValue(2, 2, 580);
        data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 540);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: <?= json_encode("żźćńąśłęó ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ"); ?>,
        vAxis: {title:<?= json_encode("żźćńąśłęó ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ"); ?>},
        hAxis: {title:<?= json_encode("żźćńąśłęó ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ"); ?>}
        }

        );
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnks for your help. by the way, can you suggest me the good place to find a simple explanated procedure to loading data directly from MySQL (transform MySQL data into GCT data structure) - now I'm doing it via gvChart plugin.

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried using any google charts plugins but a good jquery plugin sounds like the way to go